# Invisible text in modal dialogs with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, invisible

I'm facing an issue in a project I'm currently working on. I have a series of modal dialogs made with CSS (display: fixed) that are hidden by default with display: none;. In Chrome, when opening these dialogs, all the text is invisible (I can select it, but it is not visible). Using the inspector, I can change for example its font-weight and the text will then be visible, even when reverting to its original font weight. I'm using a custom font (MuseoSans) imported with the following CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MuseoSans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.eot?") format("eot"), url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.svg#MuseoSans") format("svg"); }
@font-face {
    font-family: "MuseoSans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.eot?") format("eot"), url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.svg#MuseoSans") format("svg"); }
```

I found that if in these dialogs I switch to  font-family: Verdana; for example, text will be always visible. Any ideas? I could only reproduce this behavior in Google Chrome (52.0.2743.116 (Build oficial) m (32 bits)).

EDIT: found out it works as it should if the font size and weight are rendered in a visible place prior to opening the modal dialog.

Comment: No idea, you're not really showing enough code to tell, nor a jsbin or something that reproduces this outside your (presumably large) codebase, so: did you remember to give your dialog explicit CSS `background-color` and `color` values?

Comment: It seems the issue only occurs with Museo Sans (at least). I just replaced it with Open Sans (same mixin and filenames to import them using CSS) and can't reproduce the problem. I generated both webfonts from the Font Squirrel generator. I know I should post an example but I assume I can't create a jsbin that uses MuseoSans as it's a propietary font. I did double check color, background and such where right, of course. Again, using the inspector to just change font-size, weight or any other font property, it renders fine even after undoing these changes (problem reoccurs after browser reload).

Comment: if you're using FontSquirrel, the very first step is to simplify your setup considerably by making sure you *only* use the WOFF source. It's 2016, several of the formats Font Squirrel generates don't even exist anymore (There are no Microsoft browsers that only support `eot` anymore, and `svg` is literally a dead spec, it didn't work. And since WOFF is literally a ttf or otf font wrapped in a "for the web" header, but with compression, using WOFF + ttf/otf makes no sense). Font Squirrel is ... not convenient anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After changing and testing compatibility I'm sticking to what you said, just woff and woff2. Sadly, my problem still persists.

Comment: excellent: then please update your code, because simpler code means a simpler question, which is much more managable to answer. At least now we don't have to worry about all the different formats being responsible for the errors. It also means you can now probably quite easily create a [mcve] with jsbin or stackoverflow snippet to demonstrate what you're seeing.